# print_r of an array doesn't print the values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm calling a function that creates a 2-dimensional array

```
$rowMM = array(array($incrementeCnt, $yyyy, $mmDesc, $flname,$uname,$room,
          $newcol[0],$newcol[1],$newcol[2],$newcol[3], $newcol[4], $newcol[5]));
```

Also I used and gives me the same result
$rowMM = array($incrementeCnt, $yyyy, $mmDesc, $flname,$uname,$room,
              $newcol[0],$newcol[1],$newcol[2],$newcol[3], $newcol[4], $newcol[5]);
I tested it with 12 entries by doing a `print_r` in my function that shows everything, but when I return to the calling PHP page `print_r` only shows the last entry of the array from calling page.

```
$getArray=createArray() 
print_r($getArray) // shows the last entry of the array
```

Comment: can you show your `createArray()` function ?

Comment: Are you sure it is a `print_r` output you are seeing and not the return of your function for example?

Comment: Is the first part of your question the `createArray` function? There is nothing in  your question that shows anything being done 12 times to create 12 entries so it is really unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need:

```
$rowMM[] = array($incrementeCnt, $yyyy, $mmDesc, $flname,$uname,$room,
      $newcol[0],$newcol[1],$newcol[2],$newcol[3], $newcol[4], $newcol[5]);
```

because you are in a loop and `print_r`ing in the function. You then use `return $rowMM` after the loop. `$rowMM` overwrites on every iteration though so it only has the last reference.

Comment: This is correct; without the brackets, you're overwriting the entire value of $rowMM on every assignment, not adding a new key/value pair.